# Microcontroller for HVProg

Tags: arduino, atmega

I am going to make [HVProg](http://www.der-hammer.info/hvprog/index_en.htm).

Can I use an ATMEGA8 with it?
If yes then how, if no them can we use any other microcontroller ?

Comment: Any specific reason you need high-voltage programming? If you just mis-set some fuse bits, it is probably cheaper (not to mention easier!) to get a replacement micro than to build a high-voltage programmer.

Comment: @Ranieri - That depends entirely on how many micros you need to reflash!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use an Atmega8. The web page you liked to says: "Supports all AVR Controllers"